# But are there really $3$ cube roots of $1$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

So I remember scrolling through Youtube a while back when I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NmkWRYPSmA) video by Blackpenredpen that was about all solutions to $$x^3=1$$Now, I will admit, I didn't think that much about it when I saw it at first, but it seems to have been bugging me because I have been thinking, "Is that even possible?" Here are my attempts at finding all solutions to$$x^3=1$$

---

## Attempt $1$

---

<sub>Time: circa. $3-4$ weeks ago</sub>

---

We write this as$$x^3=1+0i\implies x=\sqrt[3]{1+0i}$$Now, I was thinking of using the $(a+bi)^{c+di}$ formula for this, but now that I think about it, I have no idea why I would have been doing that.

---

## Attempt $2$

---

<sub>Time: circa. $4-5$ hours ago</sub>

---

We write $1$ as $$e^{2i\pi}=\cos(2\pi k)+i\sin(2\pi k)$$$$\implies1^{1/3}=\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}3\right)+i\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}3\right),\cos\left(\dfrac{4\pi}3\right)+i\sin\left(\dfrac{4\pi}3\right),1$$And so we have$$\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}3\right)\pm i\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}3\right)=-\dfrac12\pm\dfrac{i\sqrt2}2$$$$\therefore\sqrt[3]1=1,-\dfrac12\pm\dfrac{i\sqrt2}2$$

---

### My question

---

Did I find the $3$ cube roots of $1$ correctly, or what *are* the $3$ cube roots of $1$?

Comment: Depends on your definition of cube root. If you mean "$x$ is a cube root of $y$ if and only if $x^3 = y$", well, you have a very easy test to see if you're correct, don't you?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algrebra guarantees $3$ roots of $z^3-1$ and since we can easily see $\gcd(z^3-1,3z^2)=1$ , they must be distinct. The last mentioned approach to find them should be the best. An additional advice : Avoid math online videos !

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid online math videos? I agree that some are rather clickbaity and annoying, though I recall blackpenredpen being one of the good ones.

Comment: If you check your answers by cubing them I think you will find that $\sqrt{2}$ should be $\sqrt{3}$ .

Comment: @PrincessEev I know what I am talking about because I watched many of them , for the sake of curiousity. They are at best entertaining , but not suitable to learn something or to make progress.

Comment: Yet another mehtod: As obviously $x=1$ is a solution to $x^3-1=0$, perform polynomial division $(x^3-1):(x-1)$ to obtain the qudratic $x^2+x+1$. The other two cube roots of $1$ are the complex roots of this quadratic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, there are really three cube roots of $1$. This follows abstractly from the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra). Concretely, [de Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) tells you how to find all the $n^{th}$ roots of $1$ for any positive integer $n$; they are given by $\cos \frac{2 \pi k }{n} + i \sin \frac{2 \pi k}{n}, 0 \le k \le n-1$.
2. Ethan in the comments is correct that you need a $\sqrt{3}$ in your expression. Hagen in the comments is also correct that an alternative approach is to divide $x^3 - 1$ by $x - 1$ and solve the resulting quadratic using the quadratic formula.

Once you really internalize the relationship between complex numbers and [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) the $n^{th}$ roots of $1$ are just given by rotations of a regular $n$-gon. There is a quite clear geometric picture that is maybe not emphasized as much as it should be.